# Como Insertar Fecha en SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Tengo una consulta:
Tengo una tabla en SQLite con esta estructura

```
CREATE TABLE [Agenda] (
[Itinerario] VARCHAR(50)  NULL,
[Creado] TIMESTAMP  NULL,
[Fecha] TIMESTAMP  NULL   )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estoy intentando ingresar filas con la siguiente instrucción SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Agenda VALUES ('Ir de Compras','23-08-2016 12:00','24-08-2016 18:00');
```

Pero las fechas se ingresan de manera incorrecta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué es lo que debo estar haciendo mal?

PD: Estas consultas las estoy probando desde el **sqliteadmin** ya que mi proyecto es en .NET pero de allí tampoco toma bien las fechas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SQLite** soporta los siguientes formatos de fecha:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

Tu formato es de `24-08-2016 18:00` es `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM` el cual no está soportado.

**Solución:**

Cambia el formato de la fecha que estás ingresando a: `2016-08-24 18:00`

Referencia: http://www.sqlite.org/lang%5Fdatefunc.html

Comment: Me ha funcionado, no tenía idea que este era el formato que utilizaba SQLite. ¡¡Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: de nada mi estimado, estamos para servir :D Dale con todo el power 2.0! Recuerda revisar la documentación de la tecnología que usas porque ahí se encuentra la base